# How to add a Toolbar into manually programmed Linear Layout

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout, android-toolbar

Probably a stupid question,but I am a beginner, and don't know how to solve this.

So, because I am geenrating a lot of buttons, I've made a Linear Layout in my MainActivity.java file. Now I want to make a toolbar, but when I make it in my XML file, and add it with `setSupportActionBar(toolbar)` it doesn't work. It shows on my Design preview in XML, but not when I ran the app. I suppose that LinearLayout that I've made manually is on top of everything, but even when trying to that layout down with margin top, id doesn't work, and `layout.addView(toolbar)` gives me an error.

Any help would be appreciated!

Java code(MainActivity):

```
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);




        ArrayList<Klasa> k = KreirajListu();

        LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
        layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
        );
        int dpValue = 70; // margin in dips
        float d = this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
        int margin = (int)(dpValue * d); // margin in pixels

        params.setMargins(0,margin,0,0);
        layout.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Here are the photos of my XML and emulator:
[emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/awnjw.jpg)

[xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WfUAw.jpg)

Comment: Please post the code hear and not a screenshot of the code

Comment: @AdityaKurkure no problem,will change it,thanks for advice!

Comment: Can you try hardcoding the height instead of wrap_content?

Comment: height of which element?